# Get DIMM & CPU Socket Information

Tags: linux

I want to get number of RAM slot (DIMM) and CPU socket of a PC in Linux.

In Linux, there's a command `dmidecode` but this command must run with `sudo`/root permissions.

Anyone can tell me another solution to get DIMM & CPU socket without using `sudo`/root permissions.

Answer (score 5):

The only thing that has information is the SMBIOS / DMI, and the only way to get access to this is via `/dev/mem`.

If you're concerned with a user having too much privilege with sudo, then you can add the specific permission to run dmidecode by a particular user:

example stub from the sudoers file:

```
# Cmnd alias specification
Cmnd_Alias  DMI_COMMANDS = /usr/sbin/dmidecode -t memory

dmiuser ALL= NOPASSWD: DMI_COMMANDS
```

This allows the `dmiuser` account to execute only the command `dmidecode -t memory` (without a password in this case).

Comment: @HrvojeT it’s exposed as a file, so you can use the file APIs of most languages to read it. What bits of it to read for various purposes is potentially suitable for another question

Comment: I don't understand. `Cat` can't read this. Is this binary file? Are you talking about programming languages?

Comment: It’s a binary file; representing the memory on the computer; cat would never be a suitable tool for reading the content of this file. You would need to use a call like `file = open(‘/dev/mem’, ‘rb’)` to open it in python. However this answer is only to help someone to run the command `dmidecode`, which knows how to read `/dev/mem`.